# Is it possible to refer to an element based on what other elements are in it?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a CSS style for a website However in their HTML they do not use IDs for containers. Some of these containers have adverts, while others do not. I want to display:none the containers adverts. The adverts themselves have IDs, and so does the normal content.

This is what their HTML looks like:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div class="container">
        <div id="advert"> Advert </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="content"> Normal stuff </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="advert2"> Advert </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: Can you make any changes to their HTML?

Comment: No, I can't change any HTML or javascript. I can only change CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is selecting the ID's Parent in the DOM structure.  You cannot do this with CSS at the moment but with CSS4 there should be a way to select a parent in the DOM.  At the moment is is done with JQuery.  To get the parent div for the 'advert' ID would be...

```
$( "#advert" ).parent().css( "display", "none" );
```

Comment: This won't work because this will only apply to 1 advert and not all. If you notice there is an `id="advert2"`

Comment: Then you do it again for that ID.. he didnt ask how to do it for all.. just how to select a parent in the DOM.  If he wants to do it for all just make all the ID's into an Array and use a simple for loop to cycle through all of them.

Comment: Thanks for answering quickly! Unfortunately I am unable to use anything but CSS, but thanks anyway.